# knockout 2: how to do computed value on each item in observable array.

Tags: arrays, observablecollection, knockout-2.0, computed-observable

Hi i have an observable array

```
this.item = ko.observableArray({
     tax: ko.observable(8.0);
     price: ko.observable(100.00);
     eachTotal:  ko.computed(function() {
           this.tax() * this.price();
     });
});
```

I am getting error saying object [Window] does not have tax method.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

well what i had to do was this.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(myModel.item(), function(it) {
     it.eachTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return it.tax() * it.price();
     });
});
```

I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*this* is possibly not as you expected in javascript.  It is the context of the caller.
As a remedy one often sets a *self* or _*self* to this in the beginning of the constructor.
Look through the examples again at [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com) and pay attention to *self*.

Or if *arrayForEach* works like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) there is a third parameter which is the "this context".